# Package and visibility?

Tags: java

I'm making an SDK and I'm trying to separate classes to different packages, those classes use some other shared classes. The issue is if I made the shared classes public everyone will be able to see them, not only my classes. What's the right way to make them only accessible by my application?

Package a MyClass1

Package b MyClass2

Package c public MySharedClass

Because c is public MySharedClass will be able to access it, but the issue is that it will also will be visible to the world, how could I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a package that is documented as an internal package, not to be used by clients.

There is no way in Java to make a class public only for certain packages: It either is public for everyone or package-private (public only in the declared package).

I think there's a proposal for modules to allow better control in the visibility of classes, but we'll have to wait, at least, for Java 8.

Comment: The convention is to name such packages `internal`, e.g. `com.google.common.base.internal`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for so called package-private modifier (which is accually no explicit modifier)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1):

We cannot prevent it. Java does not have jar-private access level.

Answer (score 1):

Packages in java are flat: if you want to access something in package c from package a, the API user in package x can also access it.

Make your packages big enough so that they can be self contained. If you find yourself in this situation you are trying to make packages that are too small.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them `protected classes` which will be accessible to your classes only.

Comment: Protected will also be accessible to subclasses in other packages.

Comment: you can not hide it from your classes, but World yes

Comment: You can have subclasses in other packages. If you don't want access from other packages use package-private, not protected.